# I want to write a function that takes 2 strings and returns True if they are anagrams(any word that have the same letters in different order)

Tags: python

I have tried this, i want the program to compare every letter in S1 with every letter in S2, any ideas?

```
s1= "Army"
s2= "Mary"
def anagram(S1,S2):
    q=0
    w=0
    S1.lower()
    S2.lower()
    for i in S1:
        if S1[q]==S2[w]:
            print S1[q]
        else:
            q+=1
            w+=1

anagram(s1,s2)
```

Comment: "any ideas?" doesn't make a good question. Is there a problem with your code? Then state it. If not, then don't post. [ask]

Comment: There are a couple of questions on StackOverflow that talk about how to compare two strings and find out if they are anagrams. Have you looked at those first? Also do you understand why your code isn't working as expected?

Comment: @Riko I'm not aggressive I'm just telling you what is acceptable on SO. If you prefer I can shut up and let you post bad questions that will keep being down voted... :)

Comment: Simple idea: sort the 2 string, and compare - If they are anagrams, they will be equal
def anagram(s1,s2):  return ''.join(sorted(s1.lower())) == ''.join(sorted(s2.lower()))

Comment: what you could do is check length then look through and take index all the letters then your good.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [`collections.counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
import collections

s1 = "Army"
s2 = "Mary"
s3 = "Zary"

def anagram(s1,s2):
  return collections.Counter(s1.lower()) == collections.Counter(s2.lower())

print anagram(s1,s2) # True
print anagram(s1, s3) # False
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/Hh31)